# Oozie 3.3.2 mkdistro failed

Tags: maven, hadoop, oozie

I am trying to install OOZIE 3.3.2. When running ./mkdistro.sh command following error is thrown. How to resolved this

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project oozie-core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: error reading /home/hadoop/.m2/repository/javax/jdo/jdo2-api/2.3-ec/jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar; error in opening zip file

Thanks in advance
Jumin

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the jar was corrupted during download. You can try to verify it by running:

```
unzip -t /home/hadoop/.m2/repository/javax/jdo/jdo2-api/2.3-ec/jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar
```

If it doesn't work, and perhaps even if it does, I recommend you simply remove the downloaded jars and try to build again:

```
rm -rf /home/hadoop/.m2/repository/javax/jdo
```

Comment: this didn;t solve my issue , is there anything else I need to take care

Comment: are you able to unzip the file yourself? If yes are you still getting the same error nevertheless?

Comment: i m unable to unzip , i delet everytime and try to re-install oozie, each time the generated jar files are corrupted..seems to be

Comment: then your problem is with Maven, your internet connection, or your hardware, it's not about oozie it seems.

Comment: maven is 3.0.4  is there any specific thing i should care

Comment: I don't think there is. I use Maven 3.0.4 all the time without such problems, including installing oozie.